# How to access a value stored within a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

As per the below screen shot, I'm trying to access the data held in the highlighted Div. (With a ID of "category".

At the moment, this is returning a blank result,

```
categorySelected = $('div#category.tag.categorylabel').val();
```

I presume that I'm not targeting the div correctly to get the data? What do I need to change to achieve this?

In the example below, I want to capture the word "Work" to save to the Db in a later section of code.

[image: Example]

Here is the code, query used to return the results.

```
 var GlobalBadges = Parse.Object.extend("Global_Badges");
 var query = new Parse.Query(GlobalBadges);
 query.exists("Global_Badges_img");
 query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var friends = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            friends.push({
                imageURL: results[i].get('Global_Badges_img'),
                //friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                badgename: results[i].get('BadgeName'),
                category: results[i].get('category'),

            });
        }
        // TW: replaced dynamic HTML generation with wrapper DIV that contains IMG and name DIV
        _.each(friends, function(item) {
            // using a wrapper so the user can click the pic or the name
            var wrapper = $('<div></div>');
            wrapper.append('<img class="images BadgeImgOutline responsive-image" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />'+ '<br>');
            wrapper.append('<div class="tag badgelabel" >'+ item.badgename + '</div>'+ '<br>');
            wrapper.append('<div id="category" class="tag categorylabel" >'+ item.category + '</div>'+ '<br>'+ '<br>'   );





            $('#container').append(wrapper);
        });


    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: *"The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`."* http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Why select through the DOM when you have your data already?

Comment: Also, I have a strong sense of the XY problem here..

Comment: @Koen. Can you explain XY?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182293

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
categorySelected = $('div#category.tag.categorylabel').text();
```

Comment: Cheers, because "category" has multiple results stored against it. How would I just capture the result displayed on the page? I.e category holds "hello, bye, cool, work" on the page "work" is displayed. How do I just target this using the above answer?

Comment: @Dano007 Your screenshot only shows "Work" inside the selected div. Can you add some code to your question showing where the other items would be?

Comment: @acbabis I have added the code that runs a query and returns the multiple results. Hope this helps?

Comment: I'm accepting this as it answers the first question. Will create a new post for how to target the results.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('div#data').text();
```

Using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m46zukue/)

Answer (score 0):

The `val()` function is used to get the value of an input field while `text()` is used on div's or spans etc where you want to get the contents between both opening and closing tags.